# How to show that the splitting field of $x^7 - 5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{5}, \exp(2\pi i/7))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

I have a polynomial $x^7 – 5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know the splitting field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\alpha\omega, …, \alpha\omega^6)$, where $\alpha = \sqrt[7]{5}$ and $\omega = \exp(2\pi i/7)$.

Now, I know that $K$ is a field but I want to show that $K = \mathbb{Q}\alpha, \omega)$, but now I’m stuck. I was able to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\alpha\omega, …, \alpha\omega^6)$ but I don’t know how to show the other inclusion, more specifically, I don’t know how to show that $\omega^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega)$.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: since $\omega\in\mathbb Q(\alpha,\omega)$, so $\omega*\omega\in \mathbb Q(\alpha,\omega)$.

Comment: Do you know what $\Bbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ means?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, for example $Q(a, b) = \{q + r*a + s*b + t*a*b | q, r, s, t \in Q\}$, where $Q$ is a field and $a, b$ are the elements I want to adjoin. But that means I need to find a way to write $a*a$ as $q + r*a + s*b + t*a*b$... I haven't found a way to do that in my case.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ stands for the smallest field containing $\Bbb{Q}$, $a$ and $b$. Implying that it is closed under multplication, addition, division by anything non-zero etc. So for example $a*a=a^2$ must be included. A fortiori so are $a^3$, $1/(a^2+a)$, $(a+b^5)/(a^5+b)$ etc.

Comment: OKay, thank you :)